# Store list of interests against user in sql

Tags: sql, list, postgresql, schema

I have a user schema that I need to store a list of 'interests' against, I'm coming from a document database storage background and I'm not sure of the best way to implement this in SQL, I had thought of serialising the data in the column but this would be inefficient to search against. Do I need to have an 'interests' table and use foreign keys in that? I'm unsure on the correct implementation in SQL.
Thanks

Comment: Post the user schema. It sounds like your idea of an interests table with the foreign key would work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have an `Interests` table, a `Users` table, and a `UserInterests` table.  They should be related as:

```
create table Users (
    UserId serial primary key,
    . . .
);

create table Interests (
    InterestId serial primary key, 
    . . .
);

create table userInterests (
    userInterestsId serial primary key,
    UserId int references Users(UserId),
    InterestId int references Interests(InterestId),
    . . .
);
```

Comment: Ahh! yes that'll do the trick, whats the name of that type of table? It's escaping me?

Comment: You don't really need the `userInterestsId` PK column. Defining the PK on `UserId , InterestId` is enough.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Yes, that is optional.  I prefer having an auto-incremented primary key on all my tables, but a primary key consisting of the two other ids is also a very reasonable solution here.